# Why tests are executed with junit-jupiter (aggregator) but not using separate dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit5

I'm using Maven to build a Spring boot project.

When I set Junit jupiter dependencies like this

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I got the error

> juil. 23, 2019 10:47:42 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
>   AVERTISSEMENT: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/engine/support/discovery/SelectorResolver

But when I set dependencies using aggregator, tests are executed normally.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

So what's are the difference between this two ?

Comment: On a sidenote, why use three dependencies when the aggregate is available?

Comment: You only need junit-jupiter-engine as dependency for JUnit Jupiter Tests..furthermore the question is where are your tests located and how are they named?

Comment: @MichielLeegwater I didn't know that an aggregator exists, I found it when trying to solve my error here : https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1773

Comment: @khmarbaise With only junit-jupiter-engine, it works. I thought I need, junit-jupiter-api too since Test annotation is in org.junit.jupiter.api package.

Well, my question is still available since the point is not about fixing the error but understand why it does not product the same result in both case.

Comment: Without full pom and test code example it's impossible to say..

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: You should use this pom --< https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/r5.7.2/junit5-jupiter-starter-maven/pom.xml

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `junit-platform-launcher` artifact. See [official JUnit 5 User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#overview-what-is-junit-5):

**JUnit 5 = JUnit Platform + JUnit Jupiter + JUnit Vintage**

You should add this to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```